# Integration of $1/\sin^3 x$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

> I need a explanation of this problem: 
>      $$  \int \frac{1}{\sin^3 x}\,dx $$
>
> Change the variable $$ t = \tan (x/2) $$
>   With use of $\tan$, $\cos$, $\sin$ and $\cot$, only.

So how do I think of this and what are the steps?

#### Progress

Well I have $\sin x = 2t/(1+t^2)$ and $t = \tan x/2$ gives 
$$2 \arctan t = x,\quad  \frac{2}{(1+t^2)} dt = dx$$
 This all gave me 
$$\int \left(\frac{2t}{(1+t^2)}\right)^3 (2/(1+t^2))\,dt$$

Comment: Are you a lady or a gentleman?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112918/integrate-csc3x-dx

Comment: Well I have 
sin x = (2t/(1+t^2)) 
and t = (tan x/2) gives 2 arctan t = x 
2/(1+t^2) dt = dx 

This all gave me : 

Integrate $$ (2t/(1+t^2))^3 * (2/(1+t^2)) dt $$

Comment: This must be the first question with a greeting for everyone here... how refreshing!

Comment: Well, we shall not forget on the other side of our screens there is a human after all :)

Comment: FYI, the method you need to use is most often called `integration by substitution` in many textbooks.

Comment: I reformatted the question and changed the title. Please see [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and try [asking better questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) in the future.  Greetings are [discouraged on Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/behavior); in fact most of them are automatically removed from posts.

Answer (score 2):

More simple is to change the variable by $t=\cos x$ so $dt=-\sin x dx$ and then

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sin^3 x}=-\int\frac{dt}{(1-t^2)^2}$$
Can you take it frome here?

Comment: Hmm... I don't understand the change of variable you made :/ 
I would also like to solve it your way :)

Comment: Use the fact that $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$.

Comment: I see, but could you see how I should answer by with a variable change of t = tan(x/2) ?

Comment: By the variable change $t=\tan(x/2)$ you should use these relations: $$dt=\frac12(1+t^2)dx$$ and $$\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \left(\frac{2t}{(1+t^2)}\right)^3 (2/(1+t^2))\,= \int \frac{16t^3}{(1+t^2)^2}\,dt= \int \frac{16t(1+t^2-1)}{(1+t^2)^2}dt$$

Now, the substitution $u=t^2+1$ solves the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure, but should the exponent in the denominator be a 4 instead of a 2?