# How to solve $\int \csc^3 x\ dx$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

How to find following integral
$$\int \csc^3 x\ dx=?$$

my work:

i substitute $\csc x =t$, $dx=-\frac{dt}{\csc x\cot x}=-\frac{dt}{t\sqrt{t^2-1}}$
$$\int t^3\frac{-dt}{t\sqrt{t^2-1}}$$

$$=-\int \frac{t^2dt}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}$$
substitute $t=\sec\theta$, $dt=\sec\theta\tan\theta\ d\theta$
$$=-\int \frac{\sec^2\theta\sec\theta\tan\theta\ d\theta}{\tan\theta}$$
$$=-\int \sec^3\theta d\theta$$

i got the similar cubic trigonometric function. I am not able to solve this integration. please help me solve it. thanks.

Comment: Yet another https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112918/integrate-csc3x-dx OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637752/how-do-you-integrate-csc3x?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: No, that is not my question. My question is different from these questions.

Comment: You want to solve $\int \sec^3 x \, dx$ or $\int \csc^3 x \, dx$ and these questions that I have referred to give you exactly that. How's your question different, beats me?

Answer (score 0):

Use integration by parts
$$I=\int \csc^3 x\ dx$$
$$I=\int \csc x\ \csc^2 x\ dx$$
$$I=\csc x\int  \csc^2 x\ dx-\int (-\csc x\cot x) (-\cot  x)\ dx$$
$$I=-\csc x\cot x-\int  \csc x\cot^2  x\ dx$$
$$I=-\csc x\cot x-\int  \csc x (\csc^2  x-1)\ dx$$
$$I=-\csc x\cot x-\int  (\csc^3x -\csc x)\ dx$$
$$I=-\csc x\cot x-\int  \csc^3 x\ dx+\int \csc x\ dx$$
$$I=-\csc x\cot x-I+\int \csc x\ dx$$
$$2I=-\csc x\cot x+\ln\left|\tan\frac x2\right|$$
$$I=-\frac12\csc x\cot x+\frac12\ln\left|\tan\frac x2\right|+C$$

Comment: The constant of integration $C$ must go at least since the penultimate equality. The other equalities are well-computed.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \dfrac{dx}{\sin^{3}x} = \int \dfrac{\sin x dx}{\sin^{4}x} = - \int \dfrac{ d  \cos x}{\sin^{4}x} = - \int \dfrac{dy}{(1-y^2)^2} $$